# Get the json value in the foreach loop

Tags: php, foreach

my link json [enter link description here](http://varzesht.com/my/live.php)

get it stage_name , start_time , name

```
$someObject = file_get_contents("http://varzesht.com/my/live.php");
foreach($someObject as $value) {
    echo $value->stage_name;
    foreach($someObject->matches as $value) {
        echo $value->start_time . "<br>". $value->name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure what the question is here?  Are you having a problem with your code?

Comment: Look up `json_decode()` [in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please read how to ask an
 [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and the 
 [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: `file_get_contents() ` return string, so you should `json_decode()` the file content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.You need to decode your json first using [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

2.You need to use `$value` instead of `$someObject->matches` in the second `foreach()`

```
$someObject = file_get_contents("http://varzesht.com/my/live.php");
$array_data = json_decode($someObject); //decode json data and assign it to a new variable
foreach($array_data as $value) { // use that new variable to iterate
    echo $value->stage_name;
    foreach($value->matches as $val) { // use $value here
        echo $val->home_team->start_time . "<br>". $val->home_team->name;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks , `$val->home_team->name`

Comment: @varzesht  glad to help you :):)